# CSS Transitions not working after converting from jQuery to Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-transitions

I recently decided to convert the old code in my `<head>` from jQuery to Vanilla JS.
Basically, when you click the hamburger, the mobile menu is displayed fading-in and all the links transition should start. I tried to "replace" the `fadeToggle()` function adding the class `mob-menu-show` with a simple opacity transition but it doesn't work, same for all the links `traslate` transitions previously working with jQuery. With jQuery I had no issues at all, the transitions used to run everytime I opened the mobile menu. I think this is something related to the JS code that in a certain way does not execute the transitions, because the class `mobile-menu-animations` it is actually triggered since I can see the right opacity. Thank you for any help and sorry if the code is messy, I just started now.

HTML

```
<button class="hamburger hamburger--3dxy" type="button" aria-label="Menu" aria-controls="navigation">
  <span class="hamburger-box">
    <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
  </span>
</button>

<div id="nav-fullscreen" class="mobile-menu mobile-menu-controls">
  <div id="mobile-menu-container">
    <div id="mobile-menu-content">
      <div id="logo-menu">
        <div id="logo-mobile-menu"><a href="https://#"> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 69.5 8.57" class="logo">...</svg> </a></div>
      </div>
      <div id="nav-items">
        <div id="navigation">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://#">Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://#">Item 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="menu-mobile-button-cont"><a id="button-mobile-menu" href="#">Buy Now</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .mobile-menu {
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 0.2s;
    }
    
    .mob-menu-show {
      display: block !important;
      opacity: 1;
      transition: 0.2s opacity;
    }
    
    .mobile-menu-controls {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #fff;
        z-index: 15;
    }
    
    #mobile-menu-container {
        flex-direction: column;
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        align-items: stretch;
        top: 0;
        text-align: left;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    
    #mobile-menu-content {
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
        display: flex;
        align-items: stretch;
        max-width: 1280px;
    }
    
    #nav-items {
        flex-direction: unset;
        margin-top: 7rem;
    }
    
    #menu-mobile-button-cont {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 26px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        text-align: left;
        flex-direction: unset;
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 8rem;
    }

/* Transitions */
    
    #button-mobile-menu {
        opacity: 0;
        margin-left: 40px;
        transform: translateX(0px);
        transition: transform .2s,opacity .2s;
    }
    
    #logo-mobile-menu {
      opacity: 0;
      padding-left: 40px;
      transform: translateX(0px);
      transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
    }
    
    .mobile-menu-controls li {
      opacity: 0;
      padding-left: 40px;
      transform: translateX(0px);
      transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
    }
    
    #button-mobile-menu {
      opacity: 0;
      margin-left: 40px;
      transform: translateX(0px);
      transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
    }
    
    .mobile-menu-animations #logo-mobile-menu {
        transform: translateX(-40px);
        transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
        transition-timing-function: ease, ease;
        opacity: 1;
        transition-delay: 0.1s;
    }
    
    .mobile-menu-animations li {
        transform: translateX(-40px);
        transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
        transition-timing-function: ease, ease;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .mobile-menu-animations li:nth-child(1) {
        transition-delay: 0.2s;
    }
    
    .mobile-menu-animations li:nth-child(2) {
        transition-delay: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .mobile-menu-animations li:nth-child(3) {
        transition-delay: 0.4s;
    }
    
    .mobile-menu-animations li:nth-child(4) {
        transition-delay: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .mobile-menu-animations #button-mobile-menu {
        transform: translateX(-40px);
        transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
        transition-timing-function: ease, ease;
        opacity: 1;
        transition-delay: 0.6s;
    }
    
/* Prevent body scroll */

    .prevent-scroll {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Old jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hamburger').click(function() {
    $('.hamburger').toggleClass('is-active');
    $('.mobile-menu').fadeToggle(350);
    $('.mobile-menu-controls').toggleClass('mobile-menu-animations');
    $('body').toggleClass("prevent-scroll");
  });
});
```

Converted JS

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

  let hamb = document.querySelector('.hamburger')
  let mobmenu = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu')
  let mobanim = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu-controls')
  let bdy = document.querySelector('body')

  hamb.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      this.classList.toggle('is-active');
      mobmenu.classList.toggle('mob-menu-show');
      mobanim.classList.toggle('mobile-menu-animations');
      bdy.classList.toggle('prevent-scroll');
  });
});
```

Comment: Unrelated but pro tip: Use `$` instead of `jQuery` as it saves typing time.

Comment: Hi. In your js, you heave a reference `querySelector('.hamburger')` . There is no class hamburger in the html.

Comment: @bron I've added it, I'm using this external stylesheet for the hamburgers https://jonsuh.com/hamburgers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, transitions with a `display` css attribute kind of sucks. You can use `keyframes` and `animations` to get around this though. You will want to update the other transitions to use `keyframes` as well as I'm only animating to `opacity` in this example.

```js
let hamb = document.querySelector('.hamburger')
let mobmenu = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu')
let mobanim = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu-controls')
let bdy = document.querySelector('body')

hamb.addEventListener('click', function() {
  hamb.classList.toggle('is-active');
  bdy.classList.toggle('prevent-scroll');
  mobmenu.classList.toggle('mob-menu-show');
  mobanim.classList.toggle('mobile-menu-animations');
});
```

```css
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.mobile-menu {
  display: none;
}

.mob-menu-show {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  animation: fade .250s both;
}

.mobile-menu-controls {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#mobile-menu-container {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: stretch;
  top: 0;
  text-align: left;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#mobile-menu-content {
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  max-width: 1280px;
}

#nav-items {
  flex-direction: unset;
  margin-top: 7rem;
}

#menu-mobile-button-cont {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 26px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  flex-direction: unset;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 8rem;
}


/* Transitions */

#button-mobile-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: 40px;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: transform .2s, opacity .2s;
}

#logo-mobile-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  padding-left: 40px;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
}

.mobile-menu-controls li {
  opacity: 0;
  padding-left: 40px;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
}

#button-mobile-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: 40px;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
}

.mobile-menu-animations #logo-mobile-menu {
  transform: translateX(-40px);
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease, ease;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.mobile-menu-animations li {
  transform: translateX(-40px);
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease, ease;
  opacity: 1;
}

.mobile-menu-animations li:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.mobile-menu-animations li:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.mobile-menu-animations li:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.mobile-menu-animations li:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.mobile-menu-animations #button-mobile-menu {
  transform: translateX(-40px);
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease, ease;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}


/* Prevent body scroll */

.prevent-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button class="hamburger hamburger--3dxy" type="button" aria-label="Menu" aria-controls="navigation">
  <span class="hamburger-box">
    <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
  </span>
</button>

<div id="nav-fullscreen" class="mobile-menu mobile-menu-controls">
  <div id="mobile-menu-container">
    <div id="mobile-menu-content">
      <div id="logo-menu">
        <div id="logo-mobile-menu">
          <a href="https://#"> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 69.5 8.57" class="logo">...</svg> </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="nav-items">
        <div id="navigation">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://#">Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://#">Item 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="menu-mobile-button-cont"><a id="button-mobile-menu" href="#">Buy Now</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you dont want to keyframe out all your transitions, you can use javascript to kind of do the same thing using this method.

1. On click, manually set the `display` attribute to `block`.
2. Use `setTimeout` to wait on our styles to be flushed to the DOM.
3. Add our classnames.

```js
let hamb = document.querySelector('.hamburger')
let mobmenu = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu')
let mobanim = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu-controls')
let bdy = document.querySelector('body')

hamb.addEventListener('click', function() {
  hamb.classList.toggle('is-active');
  bdy.classList.toggle('prevent-scroll');
  mobmenu.style.display = "block";

  setTimeout(() => {
    mobmenu.classList.toggle('mob-menu-show');
    mobanim.classList.toggle('mobile-menu-animations');
  });
});
```

```css
.mobile-menu {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .250ms;
}

.mob-menu-show {
  opacity: 1;
}

.mobile-menu-controls {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#mobile-menu-container {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: stretch;
  top: 0;
  text-align: left;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#mobile-menu-content {
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  max-width: 1280px;
}

#nav-items {
  flex-direction: unset;
  margin-top: 7rem;
}

#menu-mobile-button-cont {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 26px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  flex-direction: unset;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 8rem;
}


/* Transitions */

#button-mobile-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: 40px;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: transform .2s, opacity .2s;
}

#logo-mobile-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  padding-left: 40px;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
}

.mobile-menu-controls li {
  opacity: 0;
  padding-left: 40px;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
}

#button-mobile-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: 40px;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
}

.mobile-menu-animations #logo-mobile-menu {
  transform: translateX(-40px);
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease, ease;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.mobile-menu-animations li {
  transform: translateX(-40px);
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease, ease;
  opacity: 1;
}

.mobile-menu-animations li:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.mobile-menu-animations li:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.mobile-menu-animations li:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.mobile-menu-animations li:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.mobile-menu-animations #button-mobile-menu {
  transform: translateX(-40px);
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease, ease;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}


/* Prevent body scroll */

.prevent-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button class="hamburger hamburger--3dxy" type="button" aria-label="Menu" aria-controls="navigation">
  <span class="hamburger-box">
    <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
  </span>
</button>

<div id="nav-fullscreen" class="mobile-menu mobile-menu-controls">
  <div id="mobile-menu-container">
    <div id="mobile-menu-content">
      <div id="logo-menu">
        <div id="logo-mobile-menu">
          <a href="https://#"> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 69.5 8.57" class="logo">...</svg> </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="nav-items">
        <div id="navigation">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://#">Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://#">Item 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="menu-mobile-button-cont"><a id="button-mobile-menu" href="#">Buy Now</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, it works like a charm for all of them. I understood that with transitions injected with JS I have to give the browser time to process them. I solved by just setting the timeout for those classes. I followed the second method since the first one was not working at all. I'm also using the `visibility` property for `.mobile-menu` and  `.mob-menu-show`, not using anymore the `display` one. Thank you very much for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `visibility: hidden;`

`display: none.` cannot perform a transition well.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting `mobile-menu` to `hidden` and `mob-menu-show` to `visible`, doesn't show the menu anymore. Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: Doesn't it work to set display to block/none and do the transition with opacity? or do you get the same problem as with visibility? So the opacity is just for asthetics (the fading) and the display hides/shows the menu? (Or just without display at all?)